# How to dissmiss dialog on single click?

Tags: android

I am using a dialogbox contains list of StringArray.
I wants to dissmiss dialog on single click on item of StringArray.
But it is dissmissed after double click.

Thanks.

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Disease.this);
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            final ListView listSpecialityView = new ListView(Disease.this);
            listSpecialityView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            listSpecialityView.setAdapter(adapter_list);

            listSpecialityView
                    .setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                int arg2, long arg3) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            // Txt_Speciality.setText(Speciality_array[arg2]
                            // .toString());
                            // String id = String.valueOf(arg2);
                            if(immunString.equalsIgnoreCase("immun")){
                                data = immunizationsStrings[arg2];
                            }else {
                                data = Drugs[arg2];
                            }

                            showDialog(1);
                            dialog.dismiss();

                            //dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            dialog.setContentView(listSpecialityView);
            dialog.show();
```

Comment: What is the purpose of shoWDialog(1)?

Comment: So as it is now how does it work? You click an item in the list, it shows the time picker dialog but leaves the list dialog present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the order of calls on  listSpecialityView. Try setting adapter after setting the click listener .

Also in click listener, call showDialog(1) after calling dialog.dismiss()